# Hiding elements in a table

Tags: javascript, css

I have an HTML form in a table. I'd like some elements to be hidden unless the user writes "Italy" in a text field. This script works fine in disabling the text field I'd like to hide:

```
if (e.value == 'Italy' && e.name == 'birth'){
        document.getElementById('comune_nascita').disabled = false
        document.getElementById('provincia_nascita').disabled = false
    } else if (e.name == 'birth'){
        document.getElementById('comune_nascita').disabled = true
        document.getElementById('provincia_nascita').disabled = true        
    }
```

Live example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAKh4/) (try to write "Italy" in the field "State of birth").

I just don't want to disable the text field: I'd like it to be completely invisible.

So I've added `<tr id='italy_b' style='display:none'>` to the HTML element which contains the text field, and converted the script like this:

```
if (e.value == 'Italy' && e.name == 'birth'){
    document.getElementById('italy_b').style.display = 'block'
} else if (e.name == 'birth'){
    document.getElementById('italy_b').style.display = 'none'
}
```

However, try it here and see the error: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAKh4/1/).
As you write "Italy" in the "State of birth" field, the other text fields appear **but they go completely out of the table**!

How do I solve this? Why are they going out of the table?

Comment: have you tried using `visibility: hidden`?

Comment: yes. It doesn't even hide the element :s http://jsfiddle.net/xAKh4/3/

Comment: I have a meeting in like 8 min. but if you still haven't found an answer by the time I'm out, I'll be happy to take a further look at it

Comment: @VoidKing Get back to work you slacker!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xAKh4/4/ Block display adds extra padding and margins. :)

Comment: I've just solved by myself :)

Comment: Oh! And someone above has solved even better! :)

Comment: @JackPettinger LOL, it's true... too much time on my hands, today!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple, you're setting `display: block` on the table row. Table rows are not block by default, they are `display: table-row`. Change this and it'll work.

```
document.getElementById('italy_b').style.display = 'table-row';
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xAKh4/7/

Answer (score 4):

This is not `block` that you should put but `table-row` :

```
if (e.value == 'Italy' && e.name == 'birth'){
    document.getElementById('italy_b').style.display = 'table-row'
} else if (e.name == 'birth'){
    document.getElementById('italy_b').style.display = 'none'
}
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xAKh4/5/.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the CSS display property "table-row" instead of "block" when you want to display the rows.

```
function hideItaly(e){

    if (e.value == 'Italy' && e.name == 'birth'){
        document.getElementById('italy_b').style.display = 'table-row'
    } else if (e.name == 'birth'){
        document.getElementById('italy_b').style.display = 'none'
    }

    if (e.value == 'Italy' && e.name == 'residency'){
        document.getElementById('italy_r').style.display = 'table-row'
    } else if (e.name == 'residency'){
        document.getElementById('italy_r').style.display = 'table-row'
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xAKh4/2/

Answer (score 1):

your issue is with `display:block`. This is what block does, it gives new line.

So try this:
`style.display = '';`

(just leave it as empty string and not "block")